# Create Pandas Time Serie from multiple Time Series with Python

Tags: python, pandas, time-series

I have multiple Time Series like this :

```
DATE
2015-10-10 01:00:00    955.0
2015-10-11 01:00:00    702.0
2015-10-12 01:00:00    597.0
2015-10-13 01:00:00    516.0
2015-10-14 01:00:00    554.0

DATE
2015-10-10 02:00:00    972.0
2015-10-11 02:00:00    646.0
2015-10-12 02:00:00    529.0
2015-10-13 02:00:00    554.0
2015-10-14 02:00:00    540.2

DATE
2015-10-10 03:00:00    964.0
2015-10-11 03:00:00    707.0
2015-10-12 03:00:00    557.0
2015-10-13 03:00:00    515.0
2015-10-14 03:00:00    437.2
```

what I want to do is create an ordred and unique Time Serie from these Time Series to have this result :

```
DATE
2015-10-10 00:00:00     622.0
2015-10-10 01:00:00     955.0
2015-10-10 02:00:00     972.0
2015-10-10 03:00:00     964.0
2015-10-10 04:00:00     914.0
...
2015-10-11 00:00:00     923.0
2015-10-11 01:00:00     955.0
2015-10-11 02:00:00     646.0
```

Comment: you could do `pd.concat(list_of_series).sort_index()` I think should work

Comment: Thank you @EdChum !

Comment: So does it work, it was a guess

Comment: Yes, it works perfectly !

Comment: Done ! It's the second time you answred to my question and quickly, thank you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html) to concatenate row-wise and call `sort_index()` on the result to achieve the result you want:

```
pd.concat(list_of_series).sort_index()
```

Answer (score -1):

Also you can try to use [RedBlackPy](https://intuitionengineeringteam.github.io/RedBlackPy/index.html). This library aimed at efficient work with dynamic data (time series, for instance).[image]

```
import redblackpy as rb
from datetime import datetime

series = rb.Series(dtype='float32', interpolate='floor')

# When you insert items, it is automatically sorted.
# Because rb.Series uses red-black trees as a core structure,
# and you can add items and doesn't think about order.
series.insert(datetime(2015,10,10), 955).

# if you have a list of rb.Series objects, than to construct sorted
# union of theirs keys in efficient way you can use rb.SeriesIterator
# which do not use additional memory to concat because it is a generator.
iterator = rb.SeriesIterator(list_of_rb_Series)

for key in iterator('forward'): # or 'reverse' order
    key # key from sorted union of the keys, it is constructed inplace
```